# Why does OpenBSD consider xterm mouse tracking a security issue?

Tags: security, openbsd, xterm

In the OpenBSD 7.1 [release notes](https://www.openbsd.org/71.html):

> Security improvements:
>
> - Disabled xterm(1) mouse tracking by default.

From [the commit](https://github.com/openbsd/xenocara/commit/664b617ea0c4845faabbfa8a26187b6790f60696):

> Disable mouse tracking by default.
>
> This causes extra control sequences to be sent to the shell when an
> application that has it enabled crashes. Discussed with deraadt@

I suppose this could mess up the terminal like cat-ing a binary file could, but it seems a bit much to disable this feature just for that edge case.

Is there a security issue beyond this superficial reading? What would the vector be here, a malicious shell?